# Unwanted fill color in David Park's Presentations package plots

Tags: graphics, packages

The *Presentations* package by David Park allows plotting of complex curves and other objects defined in terms of complex numbers.

A free version of the package, but without any documentation, is available from a link at the bottom of [https://web.archive.org/web/20151002151440/http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20151002151440/http://home.comcast.net/%7Edjmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html) .)

Acdording to the documentation that is included with the non-free version of *Presentations*, the following should provide the desired Cartesian grid consisting of horizontal dark brown lines and vertical dark green lines against a very light tan ("Wheat") field.

```
<<Presentations`

Draw2D[{
   Opacity[0.5, HTML@Wheat],
   DrawCartesianMap[z, {z, 0, 1 + I},
   Mesh -> {4, 4},
   MeshStyle -> {Darker@Green, Darker@Brown}]
}]
```

[image: Park Presentations graphic]

However, as the output shows, instead of the requested `Opacity[0.5, HTML@Wheat]`, the whole image has a light blue wash.

This is under macOS. (Things just might be different with Windows, but I cannot test it there.)

In versions of *Mathematica* considerably older than the current one (13.1), this did not happen.

Something in *Mathematica* graphics-rendering has caused this.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Maybe use `Opacity[0.5, ColorData["Legacy", "Wheat"]]`. Without test since I don't know how to install such package.

Comment: You could also try to contact David and ask him, he has an email on his page [here](https://davidandalicepark.wordpress.com/home-2/about-3/)  I never used this package, but I knew about it and saw him talk about it at the community site. Looks like a really nice and well done package from what I saw.

Comment: @Nasser, that email will not work anymore. But there is [another one](https://community.wolfram.com/web/djmpark/home) in Davids profile on Wolfram Community.

Comment: @cvgmt: to install, unzip, change name of folder from `FreePresentations` to `Presentation` and drag folder into `~/Library/Mathematica/Applications/`. Then to load, `<<Presentations`.

Comment: @cvgmt: Using `Opacity[0.5, ColorData["Legacy", "Wheat"]]` instead of `Opacity[0.5, HTML@Wheat]` makes no difference.

Comment: @cvgmt: correction -- to load, obviously should be `Presentations\`` (was typo before; forgot to escape the backquote inside backquotes)

Answer (score 1):

Although the documentation included with the non-free version of *Presentations* indicate that `Draw2D[{Opacity[0.5, HTML@Wheat], DrawCartesianMap[...]`... should work, it does not.

Although I have not been able to fully trace through the (proprietary) source code to identify the problem, I think it arises from a `FaceForm` directive that is part of the output from `DrawCartesianMap` or from `ParametricDraw`, the latter of which is automatically called by `DrawCartesianMap`.

In any case, there's an easy workaround: use `PlotStyle`. Thus:

```
<< Presentations`
Draw2D[{
   DrawCartesianMap[z, {z, 0, 1 + I}, Mesh -> {4, 4}, 
   MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Darker@Green], 
   Directive[Thick, Darker@Brown]},
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5, HTML@Wheat]]
}]
```

[image: Use PlotStyle to affect region fill]

This workaround is not totally satisfactory, because it seems to place the wheat-colored fill on top of the grid lines rather than behind them.

The same workarounds are needed for the *Presentations* functions `DrawPolarMap` and `ComplexRegionDraw`, and possibly others.